# Page X of Y in LaTeX Footer

Tags: latex

Is there a way to dynamically get Page X of Y in LaTeX using the fancy pagestyle or is some other package needed?

Comment: If you have more TeX questions, you can also find an entire community on the [TeX StackExchange](http://tex.stackexchange.com/), where no TeX-related question is too small.

Comment: I agree with Antal. For example, this question has been answered here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/227/how-can-i-add-page-of-on-my-document You are kindly invited to join the TeX discussions there.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use the [*lastpage* package](http://www.andy-roberts.net/misc/latex/latextutorial8.html):

```
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
...
\cfoot{\thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

will put the current page counter `\thepage`, in front of the total number of pages.

**Edit** Thanks! I added `fancyhdr`.

Comment: I believe that this standalone example is missing `\usepackage{fancyhdr}`.

Comment: Getting the the results like this: `1 of ??` instead of expected `1 of 2`. Any ideas why? MacOS using `mactex` package

Comment: @Drew off the top of my head, it may be that LaTeX needs to be run twice? Some commands seem to require that (thinking like bibliographies & etc.)

Comment: I had had the `1 of ??` but then I realized I'd forgot to include `\usepackage{lastpage}`. It worked after adding the `lastpage` import.

Comment: One useful note: use \pageref*{LastPage} to get the page number without a hyperlink to the last page.